# why starting hadoop job need password in each start

Tags: hadoop, ssh

I'm using hadoop when I want to start the job ,it always need me to give the password for connection for 3 node out of 16 ,the 13 of them work good 
[this is the output it stops until i add the password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fiu9h.jpg)

I try to copy them to master node ,but the problem still for 3 slaves out of 16 ???!!!!

```
 ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub hduser@slavei
```

note : where i in "slavei" mean the slave number.

Comment: Can you copy paste the output of this command on the 3 nodes and one of the 13 nodes? ls -altr|grep .ssh; ls -altr .ssh

Comment: Are you able to ssh hduser@slave4 from your master node and vice versa...does both fail?

Comment: @Durga Viswanath Gadiraju ... all of the  3 node is like this :
drwxrwxrwx 2 hduser hadoop  4096 Dec 10 15:12 .ssh and the other node 
one of the other 13 node like this :
drwx------ 2 hduser hadoop 4096 Nov 10 21:29 .ssh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run this command on the nodes that is prompting for password `chmod 700 ~/.ssh`, `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

The permissions on .ssh are compromised, which is the reason why it is prompting for the password.

Comment: in which node ? master or non running nodes ?

Comment: Updated the answer, you need to do it on the nodes where it is prompting for the password

Answer (score 0):

Check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file on the server(s) with problem,look for property **PubkeyAuthentication** it should be set to **yes**.

Also check the setting for **AllowUsers** property, in case it is active, verify hduser is added to the list of allowed user.

After changing the config file, you can either reload the config file or restart the ssh server for changes to get reflected.

Hope this helps.

Comment: PubkeyAuthentication  is set to yes .but i cant find AllowUsers property at all in this file